# Swift, passing parameters in sender to function

Tags: swift, swift3, sender

Firstly please don't mark this as a duplicate. I have been through all the other questions and answers and already improved the code I first had but I still can't figure out the last part. I have my final year project due tomorrow and would love to get this feature working. Thank you!!

I have a custom callout from an annotation and when I click a button on it I want to get directions from the users location to that annotation.

```
  let buttonDirections = UIButton(frame: calloutView.directions.frame)
      buttonDirections.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FindParkingVC.getDirections(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
      calloutView.addSubview(buttonDirections) 




  func getDirections(sender: UIButton) {

  //error on this line saying UIbutton has no member view
  //obviously the sender is wrong but don't know how to fix it  
  if let anno = sender.view.annotation as? SpaceAnnotation


 {

        var place: MKPlacemark!
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            place = MKPlacemark(coordinate: anno.coordinate)
        } else {
            place = MKPlacemark(coordinate: anno.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
        }
        let destination = MKMapItem(placemark: place)
        destination.name = "Selected Parking Space"
        let regionDistance: CLLocationDistance = 1000
        let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(anno.coordinate, regionDistance, regionDistance)

        let options = [MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center), MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey:  NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span), MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving] as [String : Any]

        MKMapItem.openMaps(with: [destination], launchOptions: options)
    }


}
```

Now I previously had this all working when I was using the standard callout. The function worked perfectly like this. I'm not using the detailcalloutbutton now so i can't use this function.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    if let anno = view.annotation as? SpaceAnnotation {

        var place: MKPlacemark!
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            place = MKPlacemark(coordinate: anno.coordinate)
        } else {
            place = MKPlacemark(coordinate: anno.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
        }
        let destination = MKMapItem(placemark: place)
        destination.name = "Selected Parking Space"
        let regionDistance: CLLocationDistance = 1000
        let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(anno.coordinate, regionDistance, regionDistance)

        let options = [MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center), MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey:  NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span), MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving] as [String : Any]

        MKMapItem.openMaps(with: [destination], launchOptions: options)
    }


}
```

EDIT

This is how I am calling the CustomCallout View

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,
             didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)
{

    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation
    {
        // Don't proceed with custom callout
        return
    }

    let SpaceAnnotation = view.annotation as! SpaceAnnotation
    let views = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomCalloutView", owner: nil, options: nil)
    let calloutView = views?[0] as! CustomCalloutView



    if SpaceAnnotation.temp3 != nil {

    calloutView.duration.text = "Available for " + SpaceAnnotation.temp3
    }

    if SpaceAnnotation.temp != nil {

    calloutView.price.text = "€" + SpaceAnnotation.temp
    }

    if SpaceAnnotation.temp2 != nil {
    calloutView.description_.text = "Description: "  + SpaceAnnotation.temp2
    }         


              let buttonDirections = UIButton(frame: calloutView.directions.frame)
      buttonDirections.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FindParkingVC.getDirections(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
      calloutView.addSubview(buttonDirections)



    calloutView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width / 2, y: -calloutView.bounds.size.height*0.52)
    view.addSubview(calloutView)
    mapView.setCenter((view.annotation?.coordinate)!, animated: true)
}
```

Also maybe worth noting SpaceAnnotation is a class which contents the variables temp3 etc. so in the init it would have more of the following

```
temp3 = snapshotValue["duration"] as?  String
```

Comment: add code where you init calloutView and then use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIButton` added to `CustomCalloutView` then its added to `MKAnnotationView`. Therefore, the `MKAnnotationView` is the superview of the superview **(two steps up)**:

```
if let anno = (sender.superview?.superview as! MKAnnotationView).annotation as? SpaceAnnotation {

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, makes lot of sense to me. However when I run it I now get the error ..... Could not cast value of type 'EasyPark.CustomCalloutView' (0x1003be9e8) to 'MKAnnotationView' (0x19ff3b578). ?

Comment: EasyPark what is this?

Comment: thats just the name of my project. CustomCalloutView is then the custom callout.

Comment: can you please add CustomCalloutView header code. and how do you use it?

Comment: I have added an edit. Not sure if it's what you were looking for. thanks for your time

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much. Massively appreciate your help! Have a great day:D